# How to stop ftp from downloading in python?

Tags: python, ftplib

Here are some bits of code I use to download through ftp. I was trying to stop the download   then continue or redownload it afterwards. I've tried ftp.abort() but it only hangs and returns timeout.

```
ftplib.error_proto: 421 Data timeout. Reconnect. Sorry.
```

**SCENARIO:** 
The scenario is the user will choose the file to download, while downloading, the user can stop the current download and download a new file. The code 'if os.path.getsize(self.file_path) >117625:' is just my example if the user stops the download. Its not the full size of the file.

thanks.

```
from ftplib import FTP

class ftpness:

    def __init__(self):
            self.connect(myhost, myusername, mypassword)

    def handleDownload(self,block):
        self.f.write(block)
        if os.path.getsize(self.file_path) >117625:
                self.ftp.abort()

    def connect(self,host, username, password):
        self.ftp = FTP(host)
        self.ftp.login(username, password)
        self.get(self.file_path)

    def get(self,filename):
        self.f = open(filename, 'wb')
        self.ftp.retrbinary('RETR ' + filename, self.handleDownload)
        self.f.close()
        self.ftp.close

a = ftpness()
```

Answer (score 0):

error 421 is the std timeout error. so need to have the connection until the file has been downloaded.

```
 def handleDownload(self,block):
        self.f.write(block)
        if os.path.getsize(self.file_path) >117625:
                self.ftp.abort() 
        else:
                self.ftp.sendcmd('NOOP')
#try to add this line just to keep the connection alive.
```

hope this will help you. :)

Comment: "FTP.abort()  --> Abort a file transfer that is in progress. Using this does not always work, but it’s worth a try." this is what we can find in the documentation... could you let me know if the timeout error is gone

Comment: It still raise timeout error. I have read about ftp.abort(), that's why I want to know if  there are other way to stop downloading without that timeout error.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do it with a watchdog timer.  This involves creating a separate thread, which depending on the design of your application may not be acceptable.

To kill a download with a user event, it's the same idea.  If the GUI works in a separate thread, then that thread can just reach inside the `FTP` instance and close its socket directly.

```
from threading import Timer

class ftpness:
    ...

    def connect(self,host, username, password):
        self.ftp = FTP(host)
        self.ftp.login(username, password)
        watchdog = Timer(self.timeout, self.ftp.sock.close)
        watchdog.start()
        self.get(self.file_path)
        watchdog.cancel()  # if file transfer succeeds cancel timer
```

This way, if the file transfer runs longer than your preset timeout, the timer thread will close the socket underneath the transfer, forcing the `get` call to raise an exception.  Only when the transfer succeeds is the watchdog timer cancelled.

And though this has nothing to do with your question, normally a `connect` call should not transfer payload data.

Answer (score 0):

This is Your session idle time too long.You can file after the President into instantiate ftplib. Otherwise. Modify ftp software configuration.

For example, you use vsftpd, you can add the following configuration to vsftpd.conf:

`idle_session_timeout=60000  # The default is 600 seconds`